# Recommended setup for live audio / video broadcast

Tags: wireless, networking, sound, video, streaming

We would like to capture audio from a mixer and video from a camera and transmit it via Wi-Fi to adjacent rooms of an auditorium.

What kind of broadcast/streaming programs/setup do you suggest?

We just need:

1. Low latency. (less than 1 second is good)
2. Ease of use. (Hopefully, the stream should be easily accessible and played by mobile devices (iPad/Android) without any added techie configuration on the clients.)

If you had any experience with this, it will be highly appreciated. :)

More details here: https://superuser.com/questions/762470/setup-for-a-live-low-latency-audio-video-broadcast-over-wi-fi

Comment: How many clients do you need?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov Just about 10 maximum. Last time we just had six.

Answer (score 1):

Install vlc. It will accept a variety of sources, recompress them, and make them available over your lan.

This article describes a webcam. Note, tho, that the video source is /dev/video0. If you have a capture card it will probably make itself available via a similar device.

http://xmodulo.com/2013/09/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html

Mencoder has similar facilities, but is a bit more difficult to get started with due to its command line oriented nature.

Comment: Gee, thanks, but we tried that already. Latency is greater than 15s ... No too good for the setup we are trying to find... I'm now actually looking into solutions that VoIP clients use. I noticed that they have very low latency even on the internet level.

Comment: Skype needs to connect to the Internet to verify account information, and generate encryption keys. The Skype network is created by all of its users; it's a peer-to-peer network. Every computer connected acts as a client and a server. Once a Skype account authenticates online it can operate within your LAN. Since Skype uses the fastest connections available to it, it will remain within your LAN as long as all the users it's communicating with are within that LAN.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the number of clients is about ten(10) the video conference can be organized by `Skype`, which is free and supported on every popular platform, like Windows, Linux or Android. You can share a group call with up to 25 people. With group calls everyone can be together on the same call.

1. Select the contact from your menu `Contacts` to get the conversation started.
2. Then just choose the green `Call` button to make your call.
3. You can use the `+` (`Plus`) button ant time to add people the the conversation. Select the all contact you would like to join to the conversation and press the `Add` button for confirmation

You can also use `Add` button to share your screen or/and files during the conversation.

Comment: Hmmm... We'll check this out. I'm just not sure though if Skype per se accepts live feeds from a DV camera and not a webcam. But it will look like a neat idea when it does. Also, a question if you're familiar: In this setup we will use a local WLAN connection without the internet. Will Skype be able to access each other locally? Thanks a lot.